# Custom listview not displaying the right content

Tags: android, listview

Hellow there i've made a custom adapted for my listview but i dont know the reason why its displaying it in this way:

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x846z.png)

This is how i generate the list that i use on listview:

```
final ArrayList<String> list = db_query.get_marks();
    final ArrayList<String> list_trim = db_query.get_trim();
    final ArrayList<String> list_merged = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; list.size()>i; i++){
        list_merged.add(list.get(i));
        list_merged.add(list_trim.get(i));
    }
    String[] list_final = new String[list_merged.size()];
    this.size = list.size();
    list_merged.toArray(list_final);
    ListAdapter adapter = new Custom_Adapter(this, list_final);
```

So what i should be displaying is : AB AB but its actually displaying AA BB

7 values in the image are A

1 values in the image are B

The custom view code:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);


        TextView text1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        text1.setText((String) getItem(position));

        text2.setText((String) getItem(position));



        return customView;
```

Hope you can help me

```
  public Custom_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row, list);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the same value twice

```
text1.setText((String) getItem(position));
text2.setText((String) getItem(position));
```

Make a model file Model.java:

```
public class Model {
    public String a;
    public String b;
}
```

Replace this code:

```
final ArrayList<String> list = db_query.get_marks();
final ArrayList<String> list_trim = db_query.get_trim();
final ArrayList<Model> list_merged = new ArrayList<Model>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    Model model = new Model();
    model.a = list.get(i);
    model.b = list_trim.get(i);
    list_merged.add(model);
}
ListAdapter adapter = new Custom_Adapter(this, list_final);
```

And finally this:

```
text1.setText((String) ((Model)getItem(position)).a);
text2.setText((String) ((Model)getItem(position)).b);
```

Change you adapter to accept the Model object.

Comment: How do i do it? Im new on android sorry updated with code of adapter

Comment: What part? you just have to copy and paste this code for the most part.

Comment: Change the adapter is giving me an error saying thats different datatype and cant be used as list.

Comment: okey never mind now i have an error with the last piece of code that u posted, the setText: https://gyazo.com/04ef22eed9268941556e187eaad0ab4e

Comment: Works but i get another error:  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size is 16